# Lock viewport to a specific axis

Tags: 3d-view

In Blender 3, Is there a way to lock a viewport to a specific view, for example, top orthographic, and when I drag with the MMB, it will behave as if I was holding down the shift key (perform a pan)?

I'd like to set up four viewports of my scene, top, left, front orthographic, and 3d perspective. But it seems like I can only lock whether a view is perspective or orthographic, not whether it's a top, left, front, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will split your 3d viewport into 4 parts. Top, Right and Front are fixed while the fourth part is navigable.

Tip: You can press <kbd>Numpad-9</kbd> to switch to Bottom, Left and Back in the fixed ones.

Comment: Perhaps this is a follow-up, but what if I only want it split into one orthographic and one perspective?

Comment: Just split the viewport into two and switch to orthographic in one and look in whatever direction you want in both. It's just that in this one you might accidentally orbit around and lose what you were looking at. But to pan you will still have to use the shift+MMB. But even in the answer that I have provided you have to use the same shift+MMB to pan. I know that you know this, but I don't think there is some way to lock the viewport.